# How to tell what is connected to your Redis and blocking?

Tags: redis

I have a redis cache and it keeps spiking to 100% usage threshold.

When I run `CLIENT LIST`

I get back this:

```
    redis 127.0.0.1:6379> CLIENT LIST
    addr=127.0.0.1:54210 fd=5 name= age=27325 idle=18609 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=0 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 events=r cmd=incrby
    addr=127.0.0.1:54211 fd=6 name= age=27325 idle=18610 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=0 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 events=r cmd=exec
    addr=127.0.0.1:54212 fd=7 name= age=27325 idle=24817 flags=b db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=2916 qbuf-free=0 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 events=r cmd=blpop
    addr=127.0.0.1:54213 fd=8 name= age=27325 idle=27325 flags=b db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=2646 qbuf-free=0 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 events=r cmd=blpop
    addr=127.0.0.1:54214 fd=9 name= age=27325 idle=27325 flags=b db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=2156 qbuf-free=0 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 events=r cmd=blpop
    addr=127.0.0.1:54215 fd=10 name= age=27325 idle=18609 flags=b db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=2254 qbuf-free=0 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 events=r cmd=blpop
    addr=127.0.0.1:54216 fd=11 name= age=27325 idle=21886 flags=b db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=2842 qbuf-free=0 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 events=r cmd=blpop
    addr=127.0.0.1:54217 fd=12 name= age=27325 idle=27325 flags=b db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=441 qbuf-free=0 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 events=r cmd=blpop
    addr=127.0.0.1:54218 fd=13 name= age=27325 idle=27325 flags=b db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=441 qbuf-free=0 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 events=r cmd=blpop
    addr=127.0.0.1:54219 fd=14 name= age=27325 idle=27325 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=0 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 events=r cmd=info
    addr=127.0.0.1:54220 fd=15 name= age=27325 idle=27325 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=0 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 events=r cmd=info
    addr=127.0.0.1:54221 fd=16 name= age=27286 idle=18609 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=0 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 events=r cmd=hset
    addr=127.0.0.1:54222 fd=17 name= age=27286 idle=18610 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=0 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 events=r cmd=exec
    addr=127.0.0.1:54223 fd=18 name= age=27286 idle=18609 flags=N db=0 sub=1 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=0 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 events=r cmd=subscribe
    addr=127.0.0.1:54302 fd=19 name= age=27 idle=0 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=32768 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 events=r cmd=client
```

Why so many flag=b (client blocking)? How can I tell what these are and why blocking?

Comment: The real question here is what taking your CPU, blocking conns are not too expensive. Start by checking you slowlog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why so many flag=b (client blocking)?

`flags=b` means that these clients are running blocking commands.

> How can I tell what these are

In your case, these clients are sending `BLPOP` command to Redis, i.e.  `cmd=blpop`

> and why blocking?

`BLPOP` commands blocks the connection when there's no element in the given `LIST`. See the [doc](https://redis.io/commands/blpop) for details.

Comment: Is this long blocking blpop bad? If so how can I prevent it or set a TTL or living length?

Comment: It depends on your scenario. `BLPOP` is a feature, making Redis work as a queue. So you should ask whether you need too many queues, or whether you need too many clients waiting on the queues. Also these clients might not be the problem. Since blocking clients won't cost too much CPU time.